# Finding a leaf with value x in a binary tree

Tags: haskell, tree, binary-tree

I have this question to do:

"Define a function `findpath:: BTree a -> a -> Path` (where `Btree` a is defined as in the previous questions) that, given a binary tree `t` and a value `x`, returns a path from the root of `t` to a leaf with value `x` if there is one, and the value `Nothing` otherwise. The running time of your program should be linear in the number of nodes in the tree."

So far I have:

```
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
data BTree a = Leaf a | Fork (BTree a) (BTree a)
type Path = Maybe [Dir]
data Dir = Left | Right

findpath :: Eq a => BTree a -> a -> Path
findpath (Leaf y) x = if y==x then ??? else Nothing
findpath (Fork l r) x = nodepath (findpath l x) (findpath r x) where
   nodepath :: Path -> Path -> Path
   nodepath Nothing Nothing = Nothing
   nodepath Nothing pathr = Just [R]
   nodepath pathl Nothing = Just [L]
```

I still can't work how to build the final answer in the `(Leaf y)` case

Comment: Your `findpath` type indicates that it returns `[Dir]`, which is not a type that accepts the value `Nothing`. The question suggests that `findpath` should return `Path`, which is `Maybe [Dir]`, allowing for the possibility of failure. I wonder also whether the type should be `findpath :: Eq a => BTree a -> a -> Path` which would allow you to test whether the value you seek is equal to a value stored at a leaf of the tree.

Comment: Yeah, I thought there should be an Eq a in the type signature too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your language, about what you thought the program should *do*, suggests to me that you need help to escape from the trap of imperative thinking. Let me try to offer some help, based on thinking about what things *are*, not what things *do*.

For `findpath (Leaf y) x`, you're heading in the right direction. You just need to give `if` a lowercase `i`, and think about what the correct `Path` to a `Leaf` must be.

Now, let's think about the other possibility. You know more than that it's some `t`. You know that you're really trying to figure out what

```
findpath (Node l r) x
```

is (what it `=`, indeed), because that's the other possibility for a `BTree`. Think of splitting the problem by asking "Is this `BTree` a `(Leaf y)` or a `(Node l r)`?" as one conceptual step of program design. Now, in order to figure out what the above left-hand side equals, you're entitled to some recursively computed information, namely what

```
findpath l x
```

and

```
findpath r x
```

are. If you know `Path` information for both `l` and `r`, can you say what the `Path` for the whole `Node l r` is? Let me rephrase that question by writing it in Haskell:

```
findpath :: Eq a => BTree a -> a -> Path
findpath (Leaf y)   x = if y==x then ??? else Nothing
findpath (Node l r) x = nodepath (findpath l x) (findpath r x) where
  nodepath :: Path -> Path -> Path
  nodepath ???
```

I have expressed my question by introducing a *helper function* `nodepath` which takes as arguments the recursively computed information. Now you can try to implement `nodepath` by pattern matching on those two paths for the left and right subtrees, respectively. If you know whether they are `(Just p)` or `Nothing`, then you should be able to say what the path for the whole node must be.

Lesson one, the useful thoughts are of the form: "If this is like such-and-such, then that must be so-and-so.". Being, not doing.

Lesson two, the basic method of programming over a datatype is: split into constructor cases (`Leaf` versus `Node`, `Just` versus `Nothing`); collect useful information from any substructures by recursive calls; say what the value for the whole structure must be.

If you follow my advice and figure out what `nodepath` should be, you may find that it's simple enough not to merit being a separate named definition. In that case, just replace the `nodepath` call with its meaning and cut out the `where`-clause. But it's good to start by introducing `nodepath`, as it expresses a useful conceptual step towards solving the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You're spot on with you're observations. I've done a lot with imperative languages but this course on functional programming is a real uphill battle for me.

Comment: I've modified the program according to what you said, but I'm still kind of stuck. I put the new code in question, could you please take another look?

Comment: Well, that's certainly progress. What you need now, in the output for the successful `Leaf` case, and in the patterns for the successful paths-from-children is to make use of `Just`, `Maybe`'s constructor for success. Then for the `Leaf` case, think "if the whole tree is just this leaf, what is the path?". In the patterns for `nodepath`, using `Just` will let you get hold of the list of steps from the successful child to the relevant leaf: you can use that to build the list of steps from the parent `Node`, where so far you've only given the first step.